# Multiply doubles in Python with same precision as C++

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, double

I am rewriting a C++ program into Python. I need to multiply 2 doubles but C++ and Python don't give the same result. Here's an example with 'hard-coded' values:

**C++**

```
printf("%f", ( 44474025505478620106407223274000875520.0 * 5454277033526873088.0 ) );
>>> 242573655903020442240866171189072992939998568974355791872.0
```

**Python**

```
print("%f" % ( 44474025505478620106407223274000875520.0 * 5454277033526873088.0 ) )
>>> 242573655903020398684723205308949669628048817708024725504.0
```

My problem is that I don't need the most accurate result: I need to get (with Python) a result as close as C++'s result as possible.

In my example, the 15 first digits are the same:

```
C++ > 242573655903020[442240866171189072992939998568974355791872.0
Py  > 242573655903020[398684723205308949669628048817708024725504.0
```

I need to have a result even more close (18 first digits would be nice)

I'm really stuck here... Anybody has an idea?

**FYI**:

Python version: 2.7.8

C++ compiler: cl.exe (the one from visual studio)

Comment: I *suspect* that the compiler is evaluating the first case, using an 80 bit floating point type for the intermediate steps. If you assign the arguments to variables, and multiply those, do you get a different result?

Comment: In C the `double` type is only accurate to around 15 significant digits. If you need more, then perhaps you should use some external library or module?

Comment: @Bathsheba I've indeed ever tried that... But I get the exact same result

Comment: C or C++ ? They are two different languages

Comment: You get the same result as the C compiler on python 3.6

Comment: radix conversion is difficult to get right. It might be the case that the print function (which does radix 2 to radix 10 conversion) is just not correctly rounded. In the ideal world printf would output a correctly rounded number, and also back and forth conversion of decimal to binary would always yield the same number, but I would be surprised if all implementations get this right.

Comment: If you want more precision in C++ use the data type long long double!

Comment: If this kind of discrepancy matters for your application, I highly doubt it's smart to use any floating-point numbers at all!

Comment: You are aware that your C++ program can change its result depending on compiler flags and compiler updates? A simple change as to decide when to spill a value onto the stack or keep it into a register, not to speak of which FP unit to use will have tremendous influence on the result. If you need such high precision using float or double - particularly in C++ is a fool's errand.

Comment: Actually, just for information, I do need such a high precision. By the way, the C++ compiler can't be updated in my particular case (neither a flag can be set). But I agree, it's kinda rare. It may not be clear in my thread, but I can't touch the original C++ binary at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use library `decimal`, take your snippet as an example:

```
from decimal import Decimal

print("%f" % ( Decimal("44474025505478620106407223274000875520.0") * Decimal("5454277033526873088.0") ) )
```

It gives `242573655903020442240866171189072992939998568974355791872.000000` which is exactly the same as the result given in `C`.

Comment: It looks suspicious IMHO, as decimal float arithmetic should be slightly different than binary float.

Comment: It is suspicious because it's fundamentally changing the meaning and the handling of the variable. Now it has become context-dependent, it carries additional information you don't know the pertinence of, and it does all this by no longer using hardware arithmetic, but slow, manual bit-fiddling. In essence, this solution is no better than using a string.

Answer (score 17):

It seems to depend on the Python implementation. For example, with ideone (cpython 2.7.13), I'll get the same result as your C result.

[C version on Ideone](https://ideone.com/Adxitk) - Result:

```
242573655903020442240866171189072992939998568974355791872.000000
```

[Python version on Ideone](https://ideone.com/GQboVo) - Result:

```
242573655903020442240866171189072992939998568974355791872.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

DBL_DIG or std::numeric_limits::digits10 will probably return 15.  With IEE754 doubles you get 15-17 digits depending on the number.  Your result is within spec.  You can mitigate to achieve higher precision by using multiprecision numbers.  In C++ Boost Multiprecision is an option as is something like mpmath in python

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html

http://mpmath.org/

Answer (score -2):

you could use python GMPY library, or you could just use python's "bignumber" .
since there is no limit for int in python , you could just do

```
fl1*10**len(fl1)*fl2*10**len(fl2)
```

then divide with

```
10**(len(fl2)+len(fl1))
```